# Path breadrumb crumb displaying just first letter of title

Tags: breadcrumbs

I am using the module path breadcrumb, is it possible to create a crumb which displays just the first letter of the title?

Comment: I think there is no way. But custom breadcrumbs module have the php option of setting breadcrumb path and title. https://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps someone so I will respond my own question: It resulted to be very easy using the module custom tokens with the following code:

```
    <?php
$node = node_load(arg(1));
$title = $node->title;
$rest = substr($title, 0, 1);
return $rest;
?>
```